# wc_order_query with meta_query not working when using relation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use WC_Order_Query, to get all orders where a custom meta_key doesn't exist, is empty or equal to 0

I've tried like a lot of the stuff documented on this site, but nothing seems to work. It just returns all content, which is the opposite of what i'm trying to do.

This is what most people have recommended so far, but it doesn't seem to work as intended or maybe I am not seeing the issue here

```
    $args = array(
        'limit'     => 9999,
        'return'    => 'ids',
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'status'    => 'processing',
        'date_created' => '>='.$startdate,
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'   => 'order_printed',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'   => 'order_printed',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'value' => ''
                ),
                array(
                    'key'   => 'order_printed',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'value' => 0
                )
            )
            
        )
    );
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
```

Comment: Did you check this?
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/337852/query-woocommerce-orders-where-meta-data-does-not-exist

I'm afraid you'll need to use WP_Query instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't know how I missed that... I now changed my code to use WP_Query instead and it now works as intended :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the solution:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_status'       => 'any',
        'orderby'           => 'the_date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'date_query'        => array(
            array(
                'after'     => $startdate . $starttime,
                'inclusive' => true
            )
        ),
        'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'relation'  => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'order_printed',
                    'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'order_printed',
                    'compare'   => '=',
                    'value'     => ''
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'order_printed',
                    'compare'   => '=',
                    'value'     => 0
                )
            )
            
        )
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $query_posts = $query->get_posts();
```

Thanks a lot to [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16397314/boris-volkovich) for the assistance.